# CMD/BAT get date modified of all filenames and append to their filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am having trouble with this script. I'll explain below the codeblock.

```
@Echo off
pushd "\\server\folder"
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

@FOR /F "TOKENS=2" %%A IN ('WHERE /T "testfiles*.*"') DO @(
set fdate123=%%A
echo !fdate123:~5,9!0!fdate123:~0,1!!fdate123:~2,2!
call StringLen !fdate123!
)

pause

:StringLen
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:: strLen String [RtnVar]
::             -- String  The string to be measured, surround in quotes if it contains spaces.
::             -- RtnVar  An optional variable to be used to return the string length.
Set "s=#%~1"
Set "len=0"
For %%N in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
  if "!s:~%%N,1!" neq "" (
    set /a "len+=%%N"
    set "s=!s:~%%N!"
  )
)

Endlocal&if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%len%) else echo %len%
Exit /b
```

What I'm trying to do it get the date modified of the file, and change the format of that date returned to YYYYMMDD. I want the date modified to be appended to the filename. I can have files from multiple days in this folder and each file may have a different date modified date.

Please do not mark this as a duplicate question, because I could not find this approach to doing this here.

I was trying to test for date string length so I can handle dates like 1/1/2019 (length of 8) vs 1/13/2019 (length of 9) vs 10/1/2019 (length of 9) vs 10/22/2019 (length of 10) then using if statements parse the date appropriately with the likes of something like !fdate123:~5,9!!fdate123:~0,1!!fdate123:~2,2! - I have not finished this yet.

I have tried getting the date with `dir /T:W testfiles*.*` and running a findstr but I don't understand findstr well enough to do that.

I also tried to pull it from `forfiles /M BC_Services_Adjustment* /C "cmd /c echo @fdate"` and moved on from that as well.

maybe somebody has a better solution, I think mine is a mess right now. Does anybody know how to get the date modified time stamp of every file in a folder, convert it a variable with YYYYMMDD format and then append it into all the files in a folder?

*Note: I am not looking for powershell solutions for this question, please do not waste your time posting powershell answers.*

**Update #2** (5/21/19)
I tried magoo's code, I'm still needing a solution to rename the files.

```
@echo off
pushd "\\server\folder"
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "TOKENS=2" %%A IN ('WHERE /T "*.csv"') DO (
     for /f "tokens=1-3delims=/-." %%i in ("%%A") do (
     set "mm=00%%i"&set "dd=00%%j"&set "yy=0000%%k"
     set "fdate123=!yy:~-4!!mm:~-2!!dd:~-2!"
     )
rem echo to test if date modified matches to the right filenames. 
echo !fdate123! ^& %%A
rem ren "%%~nxA" "%%~nxA!fdate123!"
)
pause
```

I have tried with the `ren "%%~nxA" "%%~nxA!fdate123!"` but it's not finding the file. Probably super simple. **If somebody can make magoo's code do a rename instead of just echoing the date I can award out the bounty on this question.**

Comment: shadoe2020, you should have the courtesy of trying the other answers, _or at least the ones that fulfilled your request_. You should not be updating your question as if completely ignoring my suggested solution.

Comment: The update says no third party utilities. Does that explain why i cant try it enough? Besides if i wanted robocopy i would have put it in the post. I didnt do that so reasonbly, i ignored that answer.

Comment: shadoe2020 , I haven't used any third party tools, `Robocopy.exe` is as much, if not more, a Microsoft product as `forfiles.exe`. It has been installed as part of Windows Operating Systems since Windows Vista. Prior to that it was available in Windows Resource Kits since `Windows NT 4.0`. **_I am absolutely certain that `Robocopy.exe` will never be defined as a third party tool on a modern Windows computer and that my answer fulfills the criteria you laid out in your questiion._**

Comment: @shadoe2020 - What is driving this requirement that no other executable other than `cmd.exe` can be used? Is this simply an academic exercise?

Comment: @shadoe2020, and if you read your question, posed at the time I answered, and at the time you've offered your open bounty, it does not anywhere state that third party tools are disallowed anyhow. It only has a stipulation not to post [tag:powershell] answers. Also had you stipulated your Operating System, listed your excluded tools, or explained to us your definition of third party, you'd have possible cause to dispute an answer using `RoboCopy`, but you didn't, so you don't have a just cause to ignore my solution or deny me the additional bounty you have now offered; thank you!

Comment: And PowerShell is not "third-party." PowerShell comes from Microsoft Corporation and is available on all supported versions of Windows. It is not available on Windows 1.03 or Windows/386.

Comment: @lit, the argument of no external to `cmd.exe`, executables holds no water, when Magoo's answer and their own example code, uses `where.exe`. `Where.exe` is newer to Windows Operating Systems than `Robocopy.exe`.

Comment: @Compo - I agree with you. I am just trying to get at the need for no other executable to be used.

Comment: @lit, there isn't one, the stipulations were, **no powershell solutions** and, in their update, **no third party tools**. After noting that the OP had provided their own `powershell` code in previous questions, I was satisfied that they had a genuine reason to exclude it. My answer however fully complies with both exclusions, it uses an OS supplied Microsoft exectuable, as does their own and Magoo 's answer. I cannot think of any shorter or more efficient code than that in my answer, _(which I have today, confirmed as working)_, and deserve it to be tested with appropriate feedback/credit.

Comment: Updated the post. Still not solution to actually rename the files with the appended result of  `set "fdate123=!yy:~-4!!mm:~-2!!dd:~-2!"`

Comment: Compo, begging somebody to use Robocopy when it's simply not possible and it's been explained so, doesn't help your reputation for being helpful. I don't have Robocopy, cannot use robocopy, will not use robocopy, and I hope that this is understood by now.

Comment: @shadoe2020, I'm sorry if I missed it, but I cannot see where it has been explained. Why have you not got `Robocopy.exe`? it is located in the same protected system directory and on every Microsoft Operating System carrying `where.exe`.

Comment: *sigh* Goodbye Compo, I'm ignoring any further begging for solutions I've already said are not possible for this question...

Comment: @shadoe2020, . what if I were to offer an alternative solution, which doesn't use `Robocopy.exe` or `Powershell.exe`? Can you please tell me in advance, which other built-in executables it is impossible for you to use? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out on my own, pure batch solution. 
Takes date modified, appends it to any filename in a directory in YYYYMMDD format. I really was overcomplicating it, can't believe I didn't come up with this prior to setting a bounty. lol

```
pushd "\\server\folder"
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /r %%f IN (*) DO SET filedatetime=%%~tf & ren "%%~nf.*" "%%~nf!filedatetime:~6,4!!filedatetime:~0,2!!filedatetime:~3,2!%%~xf"
```

Comment: In order for us to have known the format being returned on your specific machine for the `%~t` expansion, you'd need to have told us what it was. The trouble is that it isn't consistent across PC's, let alone their locales. Usually when people ask for solutions, they want one which works irrespective of these things, your code would need to be checked for compatibility on any system you used it on. Incidentally, and yes I know that you knew I was going to say it, my code doesn't have that issue.

Comment: You say that when robocopy is not "consistent" across PCs".  This works for me.

Comment: If it works for you, then great, but what I said about `Robocopy` was that it **is in a consistent format**, i.e. **mine works on every PC** with Windows Vista and above, with no adjustments or modification.

Comment: This is amazing and will save me a lot of time adding the date to a bunch of MP3 mixes I did! I modified it to make it a bit neater for my own use, so the date is in brackets and with spaces between "YYYY MM DD" like so  (with "SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion" as the first line) `FOR /r %%f IN (*.mp3) DO SET filedatetime=%%~tf & ren "%%~nf.*" "%%~nf (!filedatetime:~6,4! !filedatetime:~0,2! !filedatetime:~3,2!)%%~xf"`

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to specify your extentions so if your bat file is in that directory, it will not also be renamed.

`@echo off
pushd "\\server\path123"
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /r %%f IN (*.csv, *.txt) DO SET filedatetime=%%~tf & ren "%%~nf.*" "%%~nf!filedatetime:~6,4!!filedatetime:~0,2!!filedatetime:~3,2!%%~xf`

Comment: This does not search for files in directories on the PATH as is done in the OP's question.

Comment: And, it will not work correctly in any locale that does not use the en_US date format.

Comment: All somebody has to do is change the substring syntax for a different locale. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=2" %%A IN ('WHERE /T "testfiles*.*"') DO (
 for /f "tokens=1-3delims=/-." %%i in ("%%A") do set "mm=00%%i"&set "dd=00%%j"&set "yy=0000%%k"
 set "fdate123=!mm:~-2!!dd:~-2!!yy:~-4!"
 echo !fdate123!
)
```

*should* allow you to construct the data according to your wishes.

The inner `if` assigns `mm`, `dd` and `yy` as appropriate, using the delimiters specified analysing `%%A` as a literal. Each is prefixed by an appropriate number of zeroes. The required string is then constructed using substringing selecting the last 2/4 characters of the string, so an 8-character output is obtained.

I use `dd/mm/yyyy` format and haven't actually tested this method, but manipulating it to your requirements should be obvious, the only issue really being how to handle `yy` dates as distingct from `yyyy` dates, if that's a concern.

Comment: this renamed a file from 9/18 to the filename of testfiles04082019. I'm not sure this works the way it's supposed to.

Comment: What was the date shown by `where /t` for that file?

Comment: 0408 was the date

Comment: In that case, how is the batch supposed to work out that it should use `9/18` in this case? Where does the `9/18` come from? `where` reports 0408.

Comment: From the date modified file attribute as i have noted in my post.

Comment: The documentation specifies that `where/t` shows the date modified. In an experiment, I ran `dir` with `/tw`, `/ta` and `/tc` which produced different date/times for some files as I was expecting. The `dir /tw` and `where/t` timestamps were identical. So - how are you determining the "9/18" date you mention? Remember - I do not have access to your system, so you need to be very specific about your methodology and results.

Comment: And, who knows what locale the OP might be in. The scripts mentioned thus far will fail outside one specific date format.

Comment: Time is MST. I will be testing more stuff tomorrow.

Comment: Ok I played with this more. I had to move the echo outside the middle for loop. Still need a solution that renames the files with that variable appended if you can work that up. As per my update I did try `ren "%%~nxA" "%%~nxA!fdate123!"` and it didn't like that. error is: `The system cannot find the file specified.`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I read that you do not want any PowerShell answers. Please be sure not to select this one as the answer. I did not waste my time writing something for you. This is for someone else who might get some benefit.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$CommandName
)

$dirlist = @('.') + ($Env:Path.Split(';'))
$extensions = @('') + ($Env:PATHEXT.Split(';'))

$results = foreach ($dir in $dirlist) {
    if (($dir) -and ($dir -ne '')) {
        if (Test-Path -Path $dir -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
            # The directory path exists.
            # Check for presence of the file with any executable extension.
            $dirhash = @{}

            foreach ($extension in $extensions) {
                Get-ChildItem -File -Path $dir -Filter "$CommandName$extension" |
                    ForEach-Object {
                        # If the file name is not already in the hash, add it to the hash
                        # and output it in the pipeline.
                        if (-not $dirhash.ContainsKey($_.Name)) {
                            $dirhash.Add($_.Name,1)
                            $_
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

$results | ForEach-Object {
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName ($_.BaseName + $($_.LastWriteTime.ToString('yyyyMMdd')) + $_.Extension)
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Now that the OP's intent is known, this is a much more simple problem. Once you are confident the files will be renamed correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Rename-Item` cmdlet.

```
Set-Location -Path '//server/sharename'

Get-ChildItem -File -Filter 'testfiles*.*' |
    ForEach-Object {
        Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName ($_.BaseName + $($_.LastWriteTime.ToString('yyyyMMdd')) + $_.Extension) -WhatIf
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the output from [robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy) is in a consistent format, so I would suggest this as a possible single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) option:

```bat
@PushD "\\server\folder" 2>Nul&&For /F "Tokens=1-4*Delims=/  " %%A In ('RoboCopy . $ testfiles*.* /L /NS /NJS /NJH /NDL /NC /TS')Do @Ren "%%E" "%%A%%B%%C-%%~nxE"
```

Alternatively, based upon your edited additional example code, this is more likely what you need:

```bat
@PushD "\\server\folder" 2>Nul&&For /F "Tokens=1-4*Delims=/  " %%A In ('RoboCopy . $ testfiles*.* /L /NS /NJS /NJH /NDL /NC /TS')Do @Ren "%%E" "testfiles%%A%%B%%C%%~xE"
```

If each renamed file is run through the for loop again, you may need to expand this from a single line solution to prevent it.

In both code examples, the `Delim`iters are **<kbd>/</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>**

Comment: If it makes you feel better I tried both your code blocks and it did absolutely nothing. No error, no renaming, nothing. *Windows 10. I'm done though, already have my answer.